# GraphicsMagick can't use drawText with ImageMagik in AWS Lambda Later

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, imagemagick, graphicsmagick, aws-lambda-layers

Following the layer creation steps here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JdJo-_Y1ZIM  that specifically install the layer: https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/us-east-1/145266761615/image-magick-lambda-layer

The code works -- I'm able to resize images just fine. Note:

```
const GM = require('gm');
const gm = GM.subClass({ imageMagick: true });

exports.resize = async (buf, width, height) => {  // WORKS!!
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    gm(buf).resize(width, height).noProfile().toBuffer((err, buffer) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(buffer));
  });
};

exports.osdStamp = async (buf, message, gravity) => {  // DOES NOT WORK
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      gm(buf)
      .fontSize(40)
      .drawText(10,50, message)
      .toBuffer((err, buffer) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(buffer));
    });
  };
```

The output buffer is created (and subsequently saved to S3 successfully) but it does not have any text on it.

I have also tried the suggestion in this question [Draw text on image using graphicsmagick (node-gm) drawText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45780471/draw-text-on-image-using-graphicsmagick-node-gm-drawtext)
`gm(buf).fill('#ffffff').font('Arial', 27).drawText(225, 75, "Some text");`  This did not put text on the image.

I can't help but wonder if it's related to not having fonts as the question-asker guessed in this question: [How to use ImageMagick `drawtext` method in AWS Lambda function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57403670/how-to-use-imagemagick-drawtext-method-in-aws-lambda-function)

So I have tried downloading a ttf font, including it in my package, and referencing it:

```
gm(buf)
      .fill('#ffffff')
      .font('./Hack-Regular.ttf', 27)
      .drawText(10,50, message)
      .toBuffer((err, buffer) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(buffer));
    });
```

I also tried an absolute path.

```
  gm(buf)
  .fill('#ffffff')
  .font('/var/task/fonts/Hack-Regular.ttf')
  .drawText(10,50, "SOME TEXT!!!SOME TEXT!!!SOME TEXT!!!SOME TEXT!!!SOME TEXT!!!")
  .toBuffer((err, buffer) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(buffer));
```

Further, I have verified the font file is there with:

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var ls = cp.spawnSync('ls', ['/var/task/fonts'], { encoding: 'utf8' });
console.log('stdout here: ' + ls.stdout);
```

And getting the output: `'Hack-Regular.ttf'`

Note, I'm not getting any errors.  I'm simply not seeing any text on the image.

Comment: Try using `.font('/full/path/to/SomeInstalledFont.ttf')` before `.drawText()`

Comment: Try using an **absolute** path, i.e. one beginning with `/` rather than a relative path, i.e. one beginning with `.`

Comment: @Mark Setchell No dice.  Updated original question.

Comment: Mmm... sorry, I don't use node (?) as I can't get on with all the braces everywhere, so I can't really read your code 100%. Are you sure that `drawText()` actually has an image or a piece of canvas to draw on? Does the thing you save have the dimensions you expect? Or can you create a solid black canvas and just draw on that?

Comment: I added a resize after the drawText and it applies the resize as expected an the saved image is correct (except the lack of text).  I will attempt to draw on a blank canvas next.  Thanks.